# problems handling asynchronism and observables in Angular

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-observable

In my project I need to calculate some data in function of some dates (month and year) so once I have the dates in the array "this.etiquetasEjeX". I loop them to calculate the data in my component like this

```
ngOnInit() {
this.getGastadoRealizado();
console.log('GraficaComponent-ngOnInit()-this.gastadoRealizado: ',this.gastadoRealizado);
}

getGastadoRealizado(){
let valorAnterior:number=0;
let valorEnMesYAño:number=0;

for(let etiqueta of this.etiquetasEjeX){   
 this.dataService.getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(
   this.proyectoId,
   getMonthNumber(etiqueta.slice(0,etiqueta.length-4)),+etiqueta.slice(-4),
   this.acumular)
  .pipe(
    tap(item=>console.log(`GraficaComponent-ngOnInit()-getGastoRealizado() de ${etiqueta} : 
   ${item}`))
  )
  .subscribe(
    item=>{
      valorEnMesYAño=item;
      this.gastadoRealizado.push(valorAnterior+valorEnMesYAño);
      valorAnterior+=valorEnMesYAño;
      this.gastadoRealizadoAcumulado += valorEnMesYAño;
    }
  )
}
```

}

In my service I have the method that calls to server

```
getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(proyectoId: string, mes:number, año:number, acumular: 
  boolean):Observable<number>{
  return this.http.get<number> 
(`${this.urlProyecto}/proyectos/${proyectoId}/mes/${mes+1}/anio/${año}/acumular/${acumular}/gastado`)
    .pipe(          
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
```

}

The issue is that inside the loop for I make http.get requests that return observables and I loose the control

When I log in console I see this

[image: etiquetas]

I see my dates in the order I need them so the loop goes through them in that same order

But when I log the responses the order is this other totally random

[image: orden]

And since I need to go through and calculate the values in that order to show them in a graph, this is not worth it and I do not know how to get out of here

I have tried to use async/await using promises with the same result

I updated the service

```
async getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(proyectoId: string, mes:number, 
año:number, acumular: boolean){
return await this.http.get<number> 
(`${this.urlProyecto}/proyectos/${proyectoId}/mes/${mes+1}/
anio/${año}/acumular/ 
${acumular}/gastado`).toPromise();
}
```

And the call in the component

```
async getGastadoRealizado(){
let valorAnterior:number=0;
let valorEnMesYAño:number=0;

for(let etiqueta of this.etiquetasEjeX){
  
this.dataService.getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(
 this.proyectoId,
 getMonthNumber(etiqueta.slice(0,etiqueta.length4)),
 +etiqueta.slice(-4),this.acumular)
  .then(
    item=>{
      valorEnMesYAño=item;
      this.gastadoRealizado.push(valorAnterior+valorEnMesYAño);
      valorAnterior+=valorEnMesYAño;
      this.gastadoRealizadoAcumulado += valorEnMesYAño;
    }
  )
}
}
```

But each time I run the order is different

Any idea Please?

Thanks

Comment: when you looping do not subscribe, instead put all your http calls to an array, and use `forkJoin` with that array to get all the responses at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that inside the loop for I make http.get requests that return observables and I loose the control

Asynchronous calls may each take different amounts of time and as such may not return responses in the same order.

> And since I need to go through and calculate the values in that order to show them in a graph, this is not worth it and I do not know how to get out of here. Any idea Please?

The solution is to:

1.Convert the array of requests to an array of asynchronous responses (observables or promises)

2.Wait till all the requests are resolved and all responses are received using `forkJoin()` or `Promise.all()`

3.Process all the responses.

```
getGastadoRealizado() {
  // ...

  const responses = this.etiquetasEjeX.map(etiqueta => {  // Converted for loop to map
    return this.dataService.getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(
      // ...
    ).pipe(tap(item => {
      // ...
    }))
  })

  forkJoin(responses).subscribe(items => {
    items.forEach(item => {
       //...
    })
  })
}
```

**Update:**

For the updated question, if you return promises from service, then ...

```
getGastadoRealizado() {
  // ...

  const responses = this.etiquetasEjeX.map(etiqueta => {  // Converted for loop to map
    return this.dataService.getGastadoRealizadoEnMesYAño(
      // ...
    )
  })

  Promise.all(responses).then(items => {
    items.forEach(item => {
       //...
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi this work with one request but I need to do another request tocalculate anther values in function of the dates how can I chained more than one request in order?

Comment: You can chain requests prior to Promise.all() and it will wait till all chained requests are resolved

Comment: but with observables for example, in responses constant I make a return for each etiqueta so I have an Observable<number>[] but I need return 4 responses more for each etiqueta. How could I get then in this constant?